# Error inflating class fragment - sherlockactionbar google map v2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2, actionbarsherlock-map

I am trying to develop a Google Android Map v2 inside a fragment with SherlockActivtiyBar.

I have this error:

```
04-12 10:01:26.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.it.michele.ab.map/it.michele.prova.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Can you help me?

What I am doing wrong?

Here my Eclipse project:

http://www.michelepierri.it/project.zip

This is my code:
SherlockMapFragment.java

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.app;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
    import android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener;
    import android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapper;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    public class SherlockMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
        private SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;

        public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
            return mActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            if (!(activity instanceof SherlockFragmentActivity)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(getClass().getSimpleName() + " must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity.");
            }
            mActivity = (SherlockFragmentActivity)activity;

            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            mActivity = null;
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public final void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
            onCreateOptionsMenu(new MenuWrapper(menu), mActivity.getSupportMenuInflater());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            //Nothing to see here.
        }

        @Override
        public final void onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
            onPrepareOptionsMenu(new MenuWrapper(menu));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //Nothing to see here.
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
            return onOptionsItemSelected(new MenuItemWrapper(item));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            //Nothing to see here.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
   package it.michele.prova;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.*;

import com.example.it.michele.ab.map.R;
import com.example.it.michele.ab.map.R.layout;
import com.example.it.michele.ab.map.R.menu;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, (android.view.Menu) menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_help"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.HelpFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="tag_fragment_help" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: fragment ? what is it

Answer (score 0):

Usualy if you receive the `fragment/class not found error` when working with maps then you problem is probably for lacking a good reference of the `google-play-services` library as `MapFragment`/`SupportMapFragment` are part of this library:

Check that yours `Android Dependencies` folder `(blue)` hold the `google-play-services` `(orange)` inside you will find the `com.google.android.gms.maps` package `(green)` that has the `MapFragment` class `(red)`:

[image]

If this is not the case you can check the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get and idea on how to reference this package correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: do you have the android-support-v4 library in the dependencies folder?

Comment: I'm not next to development machine right now, I'll try to do it later on. meanwhile check the link I posted and that you have committed all the steps in it.

Comment: yes, I have checked the steps...if you try the code I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

i have spent days trying to solve this. In my case, i didn't reference open GL es v2 in my android manifest - once i put that in there, the error went away and my map showed up. add the statement 
 to your android manifest permissions if it isn't already in there - that may solve it for you.